# log4j.properties configuration

Tags: java, log4j

I have 2 classes, LogonPolicyServer and SCE. I need log information from LogonPolicyServer to first file (firstFile.log) , log information from SCE to first file, log errors from SCE to second file (secondFile.log) and print information and errors from SCE class to console, but when i try do this, information from LogonPolicyServer print to console too.
My log4j.properties:

```
    log4j.rootLogger=INFO, console

    log4j.appender.console = org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
    log4j.appender.console.target=System.out
    log4j.appender.console.layout = org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
    log4j.appender.console.layout.ConversionPattern = %d{[dd.MM.yyyy] [HH:mm:ss]} %p [%t] %c (%F:%L) - %m%n

    log4j.logger.infoNTS=DEBUG, file
    log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
    log4j.appender.file.file=log/spider.cisco.log
    log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=1GB
    log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=10
    log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
    log4j.appender.file.layout.conversionPattern=%d{[dd.MM.yyyy] [HH:mm:ss]} %p [%t] %c (%F:%L) - %m%n

    log4j.logger.errorlog=ERROR, errorFile
    log4j.appender.errorFile=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
    log4j.appender.errorFile.file=log/error.spider.cisco.log
    log4j.appender.errorFile.MaxFileSize=1GB
    log4j.appender.errorFile.MaxBackupIndex=10
    log4j.appender.errorFile.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
    log4j.appender.errorFile.layout.conversionPattern=%d{[dd.MM.yyyy] [HH:mm:ss]} %p [%t] %c (%F:%L) - %m%n
    log4j.appender.errorFile.Threshold=ERROR
```

In LogonPolicyServer i'll try:

```
    private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger("infoNTS");

    //connect logger
```

then print information:

```
    log.debug("Record "+i+":"+record.name+" "+res.getString(3)+" "+res.getString(4));
```

SCE:

```
    private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger("infoNTS");
    private static final Logger errorLog = Logger.getLogger("errorlog");
```

Then print:

```
    try{
     api.synchronizePushStart(resultHandler);
     log.info("Start synchronization for SCE:"+sceIP+" started successfully");
    }catch(Exception e){
     errorLog.error("Start synchronization for SCE:"+sceIP+" failed!", e);
    }
```

What is wrong?
UPD: Latest log4j.properties

```
    log4j.rootLogger=FATAL, console

    log4j.appender.console = org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
    log4j.appender.console.target=System.out
    log4j.appender.console.layout = org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
    log4j.appender.console.layout.ConversionPattern = %d{[dd.MM.yyyy] [HH:mm:ss]} %p [%t] %c (%F:%L) - %m%n

    log4j.logger.infoNTS=DEBUG, file
    log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
    log4j.appender.file.file=log/spider.cisco.log
    log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=1GB
    log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=10
    log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
    log4j.appender.file.layout.conversionPattern=%d{[dd.MM.yyyy] [HH:mm:ss]} %p [%t] %c (%F:%L) - %m%n

    log4j.logger.errorlog=ERROR, errorFile
    log4j.appender.errorFile=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
    log4j.appender.errorFile.file=log/error.spider.cisco.log
    log4j.appender.errorFile.MaxFileSize=1GB
    log4j.appender.errorFile.MaxBackupIndex=10
    log4j.appender.errorFile.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
    log4j.appender.errorFile.layout.conversionPattern=%d{[dd.MM.yyyy] [HH:mm:ss]} %p [%t] %c (%F:%L) - %m%n
    log4j.appender.errorFile.Threshold=ERROR
```

UPD2:
This helped:

```
    log4j.rootLogger=OFF, fatalFile
    log4j.appender.fatalFile=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
    log4j.appender.fatalFile.file=log/fatal.log
    log4j.appender.fatalFile.MaxFileSize=10MB
    log4j.appender.fatalFile.MaxBackupIndex=10
    log4j.appender.fatalFile.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
    log4j.appender.fatalFile.layout.conversionPattern=%d{[dd.MM.yyyy] [HH:mm:ss]} %p [%t] %c (%F:%L) - %m%n

    log4j.logger.infoNTScopy=DEBUG, file
    log4j.logger.infoNTS=DEBUG, file, console
    log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
    log4j.appender.file.file=log/spider.cisco.log
    log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=1GB
    log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=10
    log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
    log4j.appender.file.layout.conversionPattern=%d{[dd.MM.yyyy] [HH:mm:ss]} %p [%t] %c (%F:%L) - %m%n


    log4j.logger.errorlog=ERROR, errorFile, console
    log4j.appender.errorFile=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
    log4j.appender.errorFile.file=log/error.spider.cisco.log
    log4j.appender.errorFile.MaxFileSize=1GB
    log4j.appender.errorFile.MaxBackupIndex=10
    log4j.appender.errorFile.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
    log4j.appender.errorFile.layout.conversionPattern=%d{[dd.MM.yyyy] [HH:mm:ss]} %p [%t] %c (%F:%L) - %m%n
    log4j.appender.errorFile.Threshold=ERROR


    log4j.appender.console = org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
    log4j.appender.console.target=System.out
    log4j.appender.console.layout = org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
    log4j.appender.console.layout.ConversionPattern = %d{[dd.MM.yyyy] [HH:mm:ss]} %p [%t] %c (%F:%L) - %m%n
```

In LogonPolicyServer:

```
    private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger("infoNTScopy");
```

But now i need disable/remove root logger.

Comment: Resolved! Delete "fatalFile" appender and insert 'log4j.rootLogger=OFF' instead of 'log4j.rootLogger=OFF, fatalFile'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try assignining root logger as `FATAL` and divert the log to a dummy file :

```
    log4j.rootLogger=FATAL, fatalFile
    log4j.appender.fatalFile=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
    log4j.appender.fatalFile.file=log/fatal.log
    log4j.appender.fatalFile.MaxFileSize=10MB
    log4j.appender.fatalFile.MaxBackupIndex=10
    log4j.appender.fatalFile.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
    log4j.appender.fatalFile.layout.conversionPattern=%d{[dd.MM.yyyy] [HH:mm:ss]} %p [%t] %c (%F:%L) - %m%n
```

and add `console appender` in `log4j.logger.infoNTS` as:

```
log4j.logger.infoNTS=DEBUG, file, nConsole
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.file=log/spider.cisco.log
log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=1GB
log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=10
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.conversionPattern=%d{[dd.MM.yyyy] [HH:mm:ss]} %p [%t] %c (%F:%L) - %m%n

log4j.appender.nConsole= org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.nConsole.target=System.out
log4j.appender.nConsole.layout = org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.nConsole.layout.ConversionPattern = %d{[dd.MM.yyyy] [HH:mm:ss]} %p [%t] %c (%F:%L) - %m%n
```

Comment: @DmitryNikeshkin: You mean, still you see the error log coming on the console. If yes, can you please remove the console appender from `infoNTS` and leave the root logger off, and then check, if it still prints anything on the console? I am just trying to find out that `log4j.rootLogger=OFF, console` stops the logging at console.

Comment: log4j.rootLogger=OFF, console don't stop the logging at console, all information still logging at console, but i don't need log all information.

Comment: @DmitryNikeshkin: For time being assign it to `FATAL` and see. That should help. Since you won't be logging `FATAL` frequently, it should be good workaround. If you are concerned about FATAL coming in console, divert the FATAL from root a separate log file.

Comment: @DmitryNikeshkin Then definitely something else is wrong. Can you please share your latest properties file?

Comment: latest log4j.properties in post (UPD)

Comment: @DmitryNikeshkin: Your file looks fine but since root logger is assigned with FATAL, and there is no console reference, it should not show log on console. One question: Is your other logs files are getting populated properly? I asking this to understand, if you are working on the right log4j.proerties?

Comment: Yes, information from 2 classes in spider.cisco.log, errors in error.spider.cisco.log. But i need not all information the logging at console (from SCE but not SCE and LogonPolicyServer).

Comment: I'll try your first sample, and error didn't show at console, but logged in file. And all information logging at console(without error).